# Canonical form for romanizations of Arabic town names in Syria

Tags: geospatial

Is there a Python package or database source which would allow me to go from various romanizations of Arabic town names in Syria and Iraq to a canonical romanization?

Here is an example where the left romanization is one kind used by a US Government record collection and the other appears in a [Syrian government press release](https://sana.sy/en/?p=124296).  The Government names seem to be more well known and look-upable than the names used by the Syrian Government.  I would like to find a canonical reduction of the two into a single reliable name:

- Al Bāqāt::al-Bakat
- Al Ismā‘ilīyah::al-Ismailiya
- Arjul::Arjal
- Batrānah::Batrana
- Bīshah::Bisha
- Buraydah::Barda
- Burj ‘Izzāwī::Burj Ghazawi
- Burj Subaynah::Burj Sabna
- Buslah::Bassila
- Buwayḑah al Kabīrah::Bouaida Kabira
- Buwayḑah aş Şaghīrah::Bouaida saghira
- Ghurayrīfah::Gharirfa
- Jabal al Mudawwar::Jabal al-Madwar
- Jafr Manşūr::Ja’far Mansour
- Jubb al Khāfī::Jub al-Khafi
- Jubb at Tīnah::Jub al-Tina
- Judaydah::Jadida
- Kafr Ḩawt::Kafro Hoot
- Khanāşir::Khanaser
- Khirbat al Ma‘ājīr::Khirbet al-Muaijer
- Madāyin Kabīrah::Madaen Kabir
- Munbaţiḩ::Munbateh
- Rasm al Bās::Rasm al-Bassas
- Rasm al Karkūr::Rasm al-Karkour
- Rasm Shawkān::Rasm Shoukan
- Rujaylah::Rjaila
- Şuwayyān::Soyan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the data will likely will require some additional tweaking; [OpenStreetMap](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Main_Page) has what you're looking for.

For example, [in this query run in the Overpass tool that I ran for you of all placesthat are classified as a city in OSM](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/F3X) (note: query may take several seconds to load on your computer; you're probably best off exporting it immediately to run the query, then export to your computer).

The value for the [name](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:name) tag will have the place's name in the local language that is usually used for common signs and is also often the lingua franca for that particular place.

[image: OSM listing of Haidtha]

But, and what you're looking for - many places will also have an additional name: tag that represents the town's name in that particular language, as shown in the above image. OpenStreetMap (OSM) is a crowdsourced dataset so there may be many places that do not have an English or canonical romanization; or there may be some places that you'd consider to be a small village but OpenStreetMap has it tagged as a city; there may even be towns that are missing.

[Criteria for defining a place in OSM is here](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Places) but these are highly recommended best practices and users who add the data may not necessarily exactly follow it.

If you're comfortable with python, I'd recommend using the [overpass wrapper](https://github.com/osmlab/awesome-openstreetmap#python) to fetch the data; or you could use the overpass tool that I mentioned above, export into geojson and then convert into postgis, a postgresql library that supports geospatial functions.